# how to set Custom Action bar in android

Tags: android

```
   <style name="Sherlock.__Theme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item> 
</style>
```

this is my Style i am calling this Style Like this :

```
<application
        android:name="com.lociiapp.LociiApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/lokii_notification_icon"
        android:theme="@style/Sherlock.__Theme" >
```

my screen come Like this :

[image]

i want set style without Locii Text without Horizontal Line and with white background i am trying to do But unable to do this please suggest me how to Implement this .

Answer (score 0):

Try this style :

```
<style name="Sherlock.__Theme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

If you want to remove the tittle you can delete the  :

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

in your Manifest.xml, or do it by code like :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT**

```
<style name="Sherlock.__Theme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

With code :

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: But if we ll remove this android:label="@string/app_name"  then App Name will remove from Mobile desktoIcon ?

Comment: I mean Application Name AppLication label Of  Device

Comment: It will delete the "Locii"

Comment: we dont want delete from there we want delete only from given Screen  not from Application shotcut

Comment: i dont know but its really Not working where is Probelm

Comment: @Edge did my answer helped you? you should mark any question as a correct :P

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you want to create your own layout for your action bar. Here is a way to to it.

In a menu.xml file, create your action bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/custom"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

 ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, import it in your others layouts :

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    layout="@layout/menu" />
```

Don't forget to hide the action bar or to select a theme without action bar.